# Metaprograming: custom initialize

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming

I have to write a `my_initialize` method in class `Class`, so that it works in this manor, when used in another class:

`class Person
  my_initialize :name, :surname
end`

is equivalent to :

`class Person
  def initialize(name, surname)
    @name, @surname = name, surname
  end
end`

It  also has to raise an `ArgumentError` if a wrong number of arguments is passed. For example `Person.new("Mickey")` is invalid. I know that my code should look something like:

```
class Class
  def my_initialize(*args)
    args.each do |arg|      
     self.class_eval("?????")          
    end
  end 
end
```

I just started to read metaprogramming, but can't find anything useful for my problem. Any ideas how to do this task?

Comment: Keep on reading until you discover `define_method`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Class
  def my_initialize(*vars)
    define_method :initialize do |*args|
      if args.length != vars.length
        raise ArgumentError, 'wrong number of arguments'
      end
      vars.zip(args).each do |var, arg|
        instance_variable_set :"@#{var}", arg
      end
    end
  end
end

class C
  my_initialize :a, :b
end
```

The `Module#define_method` method takes a method name and block and defines the method for that module. In this case, the module is `C`. The `Object#instance_variable_set` method takes an instance variable name and a value and sets it. The instance of `Object` in this case would be an instance of `C`.

By the way, it is best to avoid using methods where you pass a string of code in to be evaluated. I would recommend passing blocks instead.

Comment: Good one, Adrian! I thought you might have to make `initialize` private, but no, Ruby takes care of that: `C.private_instance_methods(false) => [:initialize]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that does not use `define_method`.

```
class Class
  def my_initialize(*vars)
    str = "def initialize(*args)
             raise ArgumentError if args.size != #{vars.size}
             #{vars}.zip(args).each do |var, arg|
               instance_variable_set(\"@\#{var}\", arg)
             end
           end"
    class_eval str
  end
end

class C
  my_initialize :a, :b
end

c = C.new("Betty", "Boop")
  #=> #<C:0x00000102805428 @a="Betty", @b="Boop">

C.private_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:initialize]
c.instance_variables
  #=> [:@a, :@b]

C.new("Betty")
  #=> ArgumentError
```